# Splitting string in python

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I would like to split a sting in python the most efficient way, and the most "python-like" way. 
Say I have this string:

```
s = '"Jens", "kasper", "Michael"'
```

How do I achieve the following list:

```
names = ["David", "Kasper", "Michael"]
```

Meaning I would like to strip the names between the curly brackets.

Comment: I assume your list is meant to be Jens not David, right?

Comment: "strip the names between the curly brackets" - do you mean "extract the names between the quotes"?

Comment: How did you get that string in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded
>   string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may
>   only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = '"Jens", "kasper", "Michael"' 
>>> literal_eval(s)
('Jens', 'kasper', 'Michael')
>>> list(literal_eval(s))
['Jens', 'kasper', 'Michael']
```

Comment: If the string is intended to be a Python tuple of strings representation, this is the right answer. But if `literal_eval` just happens to work on some format that wasn't intended to be a Python literal format, that usually isn't a good reason to use it.

Comment: @abarnert yeah, it looks like a good fit for the example that OP provided. But, I agree that the format is unusual (looks like a CSV with quoting) and we should know where did the OP get it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can split it like this:

```
>>> s = '"Jens", "kasper", "Michael"' 
>>> s.split(', ')
['"Jens"', '"kasper"', '"Michael"']
```

You can strip the quotes like this:

```
>>> [name.strip('"') for name in s.split(', ')]
['Jens', 'kasper', 'Michael']
```

But really, you should consider how this weird string was constructed, and do the matching operation, instead of trying to build a parser from first principles. Are these Python literals? JSON strings? Something else? Were they joined together with `', '.join` or the CSV module or something else?

Comment: Of course this doesn't magically capitalize `kasper` or convert `Jens` into `David`… if you actually want that, you'll need a fuller specification of what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Let's add a case to your string:

```
>>> s = '"Jens", "kasper", "Michael", "Jean Paul", "Bond, James"'
                                                        ^^       comma
```

You can use csv:

```
>>> import csv
>>> list(csv.reader([s], skipinitialspace=True))[0]
['Jens', 'kasper', 'Michael', 'Jean Paul', 'Bond, James']
```

Or a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> [e.group(1) for e in re.finditer(r'"([^"]+)"',s)]
['Jens', 'kasper', 'Michael', 'Jean Paul', 'Bond, James']
```

The solution based on splitting on the comma will not work with the embedded comma:

```
>>> s = '"Jens", "kasper", "Michael"' 
>>> [e.strip().strip('"') for e in s.split(',')]
['Jens', 'kasper', 'Michael', 'Jean Paul', 'Bond', 'James']
                                               ^^^^  wrong answer...
```

Answer (score -1):

I think dawg has the best one, but:

```
stringthing = "Your string here!=-Hi!"
a = stringthing.split("=-")
print("Thing 1: " + a[0] + " Thing 2: " + a[1])
```